# Is there is any $n \times n$ matrix A with real entries such that $A^2 = A$ and trace $(A) =n + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there is any  $n \times  n$  matrix A with real entries such that $A^2 = A$ and trace $(A) =n + 1$ for $n\ge 2$

My attempts : i was thinking about zero matrix and identity  matrix   but  their trace  $\neq  n+1$

Im finding  difficulty

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! If $A$ is non zero and $A^2=A$  means $A$ is idempotent and so $\text{trace}A =\text{rank}A\leq n$

Answer (score 3):

If $A^2=A$, then $A$ is diagonalisable, and its eigenvalues are in the set
$\{0,1\}$. If the multiplicity of $1$ as an eigenvalue is $k$ then $0\le k\le n$
and the trace of $A$ is $k$.

Comment: Diagonalizabioity doesn’t really add anything to this argument does it?

Answer (score 2):

If $t$ is eigenvalue and $v$ eigen vector then from  $$A^2v =Av\implies t^2v = tv\implies t\in\{0,1\}$$

Then: trace $\displaystyle A = \sum _{i=1}^n t_n \leq n$